# Install all dependencies for Microsoft WebMatrix

Tags: asp.net, webmatrix, web-platform-installer

I can't use Microsoft’s Web Platform Installer to install webmatrix. The error message is "Web Platform Installer has stopped working"

I looked at different alternatives and then installed webmatrix, .NET Framework 4, iis 7.5 express separately.  Now i wanted to use the "Site from Template" option but i cant start it because i don't have all the dependencies installed.

I can only use "My sites" option.

Can you suggest any dependencies i need to install to have a working webmatrix.

Thank you for your time.

Comment: WebMatrix is a developer tool; **questions about developer tools are on-topic here.**

Comment: see this post http://geekswithblogs.net/anirudha/archive/2012/04/04/how-to-install-manually-with-wpi.aspx. You can got all dependencies you need to have installed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue. I did not use web platform installer. When i started the webmatrix, it asked for an update. I looked at what it wanted to install and it also showed the links. I manually went to those links and installed all the required dependencies.

Now my webmatrix works perfectly fine. Thank you all for your responses

Answer (score 1):

There are a few more dependencies you might be missing:

- ASP.NET Web Pages
- Web Deploy
- Web Platform Installer itself

The easiest way to get it all working is to have Web Platform Installer take care of these dependencies for you, so we should probably take a look at why Web Platform Installer stops working. Is there an error log that it spits out that you can post?